# Chrome video tag can't play fragmented mp4 stream

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, microsoft-edge, chromium

We use `<video>` to play fMP4 stream (Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)).

```html
<video muted autoplay playsinline>
  <source src='http://10.12.13.250:8080/5f6c457205c38e6a18ef991b/0e70e1cdee8b21af.live.mp4' />
</video>
```

The url of the page is `localhost:3000`, so we are trying to display the stream across origin.

It worked in Chrome several months ago. But for now(Chrome 86), it can't work. Nothing is played. The same issue occurs in Microsoft New Edge since it uses the same engine of Chrome.

However the same code works in Firefox (v82.0.2).

We notice that there was a break [change](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/07/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default) of Chrome recently. So we disable `chrome://flags/#reduced-referrer-granularity`. But the issue still remains.

How can we let `<video>` play fragmented mp4 in Chrome (new Edge), again?

Comment: Did you see any warning or error message in the console? does video gets play if you try to play locally, not on a cross-origin? If possible for you then please try to share the sample fmp4 codec H.264 video. Also, let us know about your streaming code. We can try to make a test with it to check for the issue.

Comment: No warning or error message. VLC and Firefox can play the stream. It seems that cross-origin is not the root cause since I disabled reduced-referrer-granularity. I'm going to record the stream and try my best to share the stream to you.

Comment: It is very hard to share the stream to the internet. However, I can share the repo steps here. 1. Download zlmediakit from 'https://github.com/xia-chu/ZLMediaKit'. We can run the zlmediakit docker directly instead of building from source code. 2. Push stream, use 'ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" -vcodec libx264  -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://127.0.0.1/live/test'. 3. Write a simple page, which contains `<video src='http://127.0.0.1/live/test.live.mp4'></video>`. Open it in Chrome/Edge/Safari.

Comment: We build a test stream on internet. `http://cam.jujiucloud.com/live/test.live.mp4`. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to test the stream on my side that you shared in the comment.

I got similar results with the Edge Chromium browser and Goole Chrome browser, That is the stream is not playing. However, it is playing with the Firefox browser.

I confirm the codec of the stream using the VLC player.

[image]

I try to run the code below and try to check whether this video type and codec can work with the chromium browsers or not.

```js
function supportType(e,vidType,codType) { 
  var vid = document.createElement('video');
  isSupp = vid.canPlayType(vidType+';codecs="'+codType+'"');
  if (isSupp == "") {
    isSupp = "No";
  }
  e.target.parentNode.innerHTML = "Answer: " + isSupp;
}
```

```html
<p>Can my browser play MP4 videos? <span>
<button onclick="supportType(event,'video/mp4','H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)')" type="button">Test</button>
</span></p>
```

Test result in Edge Chromium browser and Goole Chrome browser:

[image]

It looks like this codec is not supported by the Chromium platform. I suggest trying to use the supported codec for your stream may help you to play your stream in the Chromium browsers.

Comment: Chromium supported it several months ago. What happens recently?

Comment: The reason we insisted on Microsoft New Edge is that it was the only one browser which could play HEVC(H.265) video in the universe. We tried it successfully, and we had thought that we had made the breakthrough. But now, it can't even play H.264 video.

Comment: By the way, what codecs does chromium support for 'video/mp4'?

Comment: You can refer to this [document](https://www.chromium.org/audio-video) to check the supported codecs for the Chromium platform. You can also try to refer to this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1541739/h-264-video-support-in-chromium-missing-codec) may help to get some more information regarding this issue.

Comment: Saw the document, nothing helpful. Tried 'https://tools.woolyss.com/html5-audio-video-tester/', it seems that microsoft new edge can play 'h264/mp4' and 'h265/mp4' video nicely. So what can I do to let browsers play my video stream?

Comment: The [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1541739/h-264-video-support-in-chromium-missing-codec) is helpful. It lists all the supported codecs. Now we are trying to change our codec. Thank you very much.

Comment: I did some research, avc1/mp4 should be supported by Chromium. It is probably a bug of Chromium.

Comment: There are many variations in the codecs. If you think that this issue is related to the Chromium platform then I suggest you create a new issue [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Comment: Created. See 'https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1145478'.

Comment: It's been fixed. The video can be nicely played on Chrome Canary. Hope it could be integrated into Chromium Edge soon.

Comment: Thanks for informing us that issue has been fixed. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and suggestion.